# Vscode SSH-extension puts an $ before username

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

When I try to open an ssh connection with the VS Code extension by saying `ssh <user>@<hostaddress>`, when I am asked for my password, it says I should enter the password for `$<user>@<hostaddress>`. As a consequence, I cannot successfully connect, because the user does not exist.

Comment: You have tagged your question with `windows-subsystem-for-linux` , are you testing Remote-SSH  extension with WSL  or you just want to connect  VSCode to your local WSL? For the latter you don't need ssh but Remote-WSL extension .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i've bypassed it by enabling "Remote.SSH" option in VS Code settings/extentions/Remote-SSH.

[remotessh-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn6ML.png)

Hope it works for you too :)